# Model.get_weights in custom loss function TF 2.0

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am designing a custom loss function in which i need to access model weights in the loss function.

Code:

```
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    model.get_weights()
    return K.sum(-(y_true * K.log(y_pred)))/batch_size + ((error2/num_conv)*scal_f)
```

But when I try to access weights in loss function by calling get_weights() it gives me following error

> Error = "Cannot get value inside Tensorflow graph function."

Comment: Please add an explanation for what are you trying to do? and what problem you are running into in details, so other developers can help you to find a solution

Comment: Why is no one helping me am i I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with some help that the problem was by default eager execution in tf 2.0 I just turned it off and it worked